# Can't access element of object/dictionary in my JSON file? Node.js

Tags: node.js, json, discord.js

I'm creating a discord bot and I need to store a list of users (and one YT Link that they want each) in a JSON file.  Then, when a user types `%users` into discord, the bot returns all the users and their YT link.  These are stored as dictionaries  It would do this by finding how many json files are in a folder ("./JSON") and cycling through each file and fetching the user IDs and links.  However, when I read the file with `fs.readFile` and try to get the relevant element of the dictionary (`var YT = data["Video"];`), I meet the error: `Can't read property of 'Video' undefined.`

Here is the code that is erroring:

```
fs.readFile(file, (data) => {
  var YT = data["Video"];
  var FinalUserID = data["ID"];
  msg.channel.send("ID:" + FinalUserID + ", Link: " + YT);

});
```

and here is the main block, for more context:

```
  if(msg.content.startsWith(prefix + "users")) 
  {
    //finds how many files are in the directory JSON.
    const fs = require('fs');
    const dir = './JSON';
    fs.readdir(dir, (err, files) => {
      var filesJSON = files.length;
      if(filesJSON == 0) 
      {
        msg.channel.send("No users have been added.");
        console.log("User did %users and no users were printed. ");     
      }
      else if(filesJSON > 0)
      {
        const path = require('path');

        //joining path of directory
        const DirPath = path.join(__dirname, 'JSON');

        //passing DirPath and callback function.
        fs.readdir(DirPath, function(err, files) {
          //Error catching/handling:
          if(err)
          {
            return console.log('Unable to scan directory: ' + err);
            return msg.channel.send('Unable to scan directory: ' + err);
          }
          //listing all files using forEach
          files.forEach(function(file) {
            //fetching the actual contents of each file:
            fs.readFile(file, (data) => {
              var YT = data["Video"];
              var FinalUserID = data["ID"];
              msg.channel.send("ID:" + FinalUserID + ", Link: " + YT);

            });
          });
        });
        console.log("User did %users and the users in 'users' array was printed. "); 
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of `readFile` callback - [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback):

```js
fs.readFile(file, (err, data) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  var YT = data["Video"];
  var FinalUserID = data["ID"];
  msg.channel.send("ID:" + FinalUserID + ", Link: " + YT);
});
```

Comment: but then I get the error:
illegal operation on directory

Comment: Is this error related to the original question?
Anyway, make sure that you are not reading a directory with `fs`.